# doesnt return the right boolean

Tags: c++, oop, boolean, banking

```
bool Account::withdraw(double amt) {

    if (amt < balance){
        balance = balance - amt;
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Is there anything wrong with my code?

Comment: What are the values of `balance` and `amt` when the wrong boolean is returned? Also, think of when the customer wants to withdraw the exact amount of the `balance`, what boolean do you think is returned?

Comment: Give the whole snippet of the Account class, so that it would be easier for us to get the problem. It would be great if you give the snap of the wrong output! You can see how to ask [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

If you have a balance of `x`, you should be able to withdraw a balance of `x`.

Therefore, you should be checking if `amt <= balance`, **not** if `amt < balance` as this excludes the case where `amt == balance`.

Simply update your code to this:

```
bool Account::withdraw(double amt) {

    if (amt <= balance){
        balance = balance - amt;
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I already tried (amt <= balance), it still returns 0 instead of 1

Comment: For what value of amt and balance does it return 0, when it should be returning 1?

Comment: cout << "Withdraw 150.00: " << account.withdraw(150.00) << endl;
    cout << "Deposit 22.50: " << account.deposit(22.50) << endl;
    cout << "Withdraw 47.62: " << account.withdraw(47.62) << endl;
    cout << "Withdraw 400.00: " << account.withdraw(400.00) << endl;

this is the int main ()

Comment: Okay, can you tell me the output?

Comment: Also, if you could, edit your question with your code for `Deposit`. That could be the source of the problem.

Comment: Withdraw 150.00: 0
Deposit 22.50: 1
Withdraw 47.62: 0
Withdraw 400.00: 0

Comment: bool Account::deposit(double amt) {
  balance = balance + amt;
  return true;
 }

Comment: @nouveau when should the withdraw be returning 1? It seems to mee in all those cases it should be returning 0.